# what do you call someone who doesn't want to pay for another person's skills

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who doesn't want to pay for another person's skills? They want the best, but can't pay for it or think you charge too much because they think it is easy and cheap to do - always looking for the lowest price. They will seek out individuals who are not skilled and then try to use their prices to justify why you're charging too much. "I found three other people who charge half of what you want!"

Comment: Miserley people display the disparaging behaviour you describe.

Comment: Not adding this as an answer, since I don't think it 100% fits with the question, but there's also the concept of the choosing beggar. See the [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=choosing%20beggar) and [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChoosingBeggars/).

Comment: Not adding as an answer, but in this situation I've used any number of pejorative words that would be out of place in very polite company. They don't describe the specific problem, but they suffice.

Answer (score 9):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheapskate) has

> **cheapskate** noun: a miserly or stingy person
>
> especially : one who tries to avoid paying a fair share of costs or
>   expenses

Answer (score 2):

The word `skinflint` comes to mind:

> a person who would save, gain, or extort money by any means : miser

Example of usage:

> He was so mean, would ask the barber for a free haircut. But the skinflint was actually a very wealthy man.

Word origin of 'skinflint'

> C18: referring to a person so avaricious that he would skin (swindle)
>   a flint

In other words, a skinflint would swindle a stone to save money.

Comment: *chiseler* is a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

The all American in origin and slang:  **tightwad**   [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/201943?redirectedFrom=tightwad#eid)

> - slang (orig. and chiefly U.S.).
> - A miserly person; one who keeps his wad of paper money tightly    rolled. Also attributive and (rarely) as adj. Also figurative.

Answer (score -1):

For the element of haggling in a disingenuous manner, by using tactics such as claiming that another provider is cheaper, without mention that it is also of lower quality, you might consider **[huckster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/huckster)** as given by Merriam-Webster:

> especially : one who sells or advertises something in an aggressive, dishonest, or annoying way

Answer (score -2):

A single word could be **shrewd**. Lexico has this [definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/shrewd)

> **shrewd**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1** Having or showing sharp powers of judgement; astute.
>   *General manager Danny Ferry made a shrewd move in signing the 32-year-old power forward.*

---

A *phrase* that could be used to describe what the person does, is given in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drive-a-hard-bargain) as

> **drive a hard bargain**
>   INFORMAL
>
> to expect a lot in exchange for what you pay or do
>   *He was a man who drove a hard bargain, so it was said.*

Comment: Not specific enough.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I didn't realise everyone is expecting a perjorative word: this answer is not a "value judgement". The site is about the use of English.